# CRM Analytics - Dynamic Max Range in Polar Gauge with Trellis

Tags: einstein-analytics, crm-analytics

I am trying to show a series of polar gauge charts in which the max range should be set dynamically based on one field (quota) and the completion based on another field (achievement). This works well for an individual chart but not when I am using a trellis (all cirles in green are at 100%).

I am struggling to get the dynamic binding to work - thanks for your help.

[image: View of polar gauge]
[image: Referencing dynamic binding]
[image: Showing linked binding]